# How do I show a message when one of the buttons is pressed and one or all inputs are empty?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if you could help me with this. I want to show a message to the user who presses a button without filling the fields before pressing the button. This is the code:

Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/santimorelle23/1L420v87/2/

```
<body>
<div id="contLayout">
    <h1 id="header">Calculator</h1>
    <div id="contInputs">
        <input type="number" required id="num1" class="inputs">
        <input type="number" id="num2" class="inputs">
    </div>
    <div id="contButtons">
        <p>Operators - Tools</p>
        <button class="operatorIcon" id="+">+</button>
        <button class="operatorIcon" id="-">-</button>
        <button class="operatorIcon" id="x">x</button>
        <button class="operatorIcon" id="/">/</button>
        <button class="operatorIcon" id="C">C</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Calculator/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways of *"showing a message"*.

**1. You can use one of the oldest browser's functionality: the **alert** dialog.**

Whenever you press any button, you can use the DOM API functions to get your inputs, check their values, and react over empty values.

```js
function doSomething(){
  var a = document.querySelector('#your-first-input-id');
  var b = document.querySelector('#your-second-input-id');

  if (!a.value || !b.value)
    return alert('No empty values allowed');
}
```

**2. You can dynamically append a text into your DOM**

The browser's alert dialog has an awful design. People often hate them.

Another approach is to dynamically append a text into your DOM, so that you can style it the way you prefer.

```js
function doSomething(){
  var a = document.querySelector('#your-first-input-id');
  var b = document.querySelector('#your-second-input-id');

  if (!a.value || !b.value)
    document.querySelector('#your-error-div-id').innerHTML = 'Fields cannot be empty';
}
```

**3. You can use the browser's native input validators by using `required` attribute:**

```html
<input type="number" required />
```

This way, the browser will do the hard job for you, displaying a message indicating that the input can't be empty.

This approach takes from you the responsibility of checking inputs' values or even displaying a message on the UI. It lets the browser entirely handle this behavior for you.

However, it makes your job a bit hard because:

1) It requires you to wrap your inputs within a `form` element *and* that your buttons have a `type="submit"` attribute.

2) Whenever you press a Submit button, your browser refreshes. To avoid this default behavior, you need to prevent the button's default behavior:

```js
function onSomething(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ... do anything
}
```

Comment: I think your third idea needs a form and a submit button to be triggered.

Comment: Indeed, @Hardood, it does! I've edited my answer to include your point. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @Stanley Sathler.

Comment: Thanks for your help @StanleySathler! It's crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, these codes will help.

Javascript:

```
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operatorIcon");
        allButtons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function() {
               alert(`you press ${this.id}`)
            })
        });
```

Updated :

Javascript:

```
let input1 = document.getElementById("num1");
let input2 = document.getElementById("num2");

function isInputsEmpty() {
    if (input1.value === "" || input2.value === "") {
        alert("input is empty")
    }
}

const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operatorIcon");
allButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        isInputsEmpty();
    })
});
```

Comment: Great code for the button click and message showing. But i think he also needs to validate the values of inputs and then show the message based on the result of the valudation. This part is missing in your solution, so try to edit your answer and include it.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  In your function you already grab the input values:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value)
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value)
```

So you can say that if either one is an empty string, make a `div` visible with an error message

```html
<div class="error-message">
  Please enter a number for both inputs
</div>
```

```js
if (num1 === "" || num2 === ""){
  documen.querySelector('.error-message').classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.error-message{
   display: none;
}
.error-message.active{
  display: block;
}
```

Obviously you can customize this to suit your needs, but that's the basic gist.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude!